# How to move the page number to the bottom of the page for a single page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am making a book with the `fancyhdr` package. I have some headers that put page numbers on the top corners of the pages. On pages that are started by `\chapter`, LaTeX moves the line number down to the middle of the bottom of the page and removes it from the top. (Apparently it does something like changing the `pagestyle` to `plain` for a single page.) That's fine, but I want to do the same thing on a certain single page that is not a chapter beginning.

What is the command that LaTeX is using to move clear the header and show the page number in the bottom of the page for a single page?

Comment: `\thispagestyle{plain}`

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that you could use `\thispagestyle{plain}`.

Using `\thispagestyle{empty}` would remove the page number.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I've edited the answer and added backticks around the LaTeX code snippets.